# Use mdfind to identify all encrypted dmg?

Tags: macos, command-line, spotlight, dmg

Can someone suggest a clever way to identify all dmg that are encrypted?

My only idea is rather complicated. use `mdfind '(kMDItemFSName=*.dmg)'` and then test the response from `hdiutil imageinfo` and log the result of those that ask for a password. Thanks to the answer and comments, the following command runs all the dmg through hdiutil, but I can't figure out how to identify the ones that give an error. Any ideas?

```
mdfind -0 "kMDItemFSName=*.dmg" |xargs -0 -I{} -L 1 hdiutil imageinfo {}
```

Comment: AFAIK There is not an extended file attribute for encrypted `.dmg` files, e.g. using `ls -l@` might show `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate` there is not a `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemEncrypted`.  You can see the _metadata attributes_ of a file using `mdls`.  So using `hdiutil imageinfo` is probably the only way to get directly from the file itself. You could script it and pipe the output of `hdiutil imageinfo` to `grep`, etc. and further process it so the final output might be list of files that are encrypted, etc. It all depends on really what you're trying to accomplish to begin with.

Comment: Hi. I only want to know which dmg are encrypted. To make a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the present time on my local disk I have 88 **.dmg** files, three of which are encrypted. Before running the command line below I didn't know how many encrypted **.dmg** files I had and if any, where they were.  So while the following command line may look convoluted nonetheless it should work as advertised.

Open **Terminal** and copy and paste the entire command line below, as is, into the **Terminal** then press **Enter**.

```
mdfind '(kMDItemFSName=*.dmg)' | while IFS= read -r line; do printf "$line " & hdiutil isencrypted "$line"; done > dmg_file_list; grep ': YES' dmg_file_list > encrypted_dmg_file_list; clear; cat encrypted_dmg_file_list
```

This will create two files, **dmg_file_list** and **encrypted_dmg_file_list**, and output the contents of the latter to the Terminal. The files can also be opened in a text editor.

The files will contain the **fully qualified pathname** of the **.dmg** files followed by a space and either **encrypted: NO** or **encrypted: YES** in the **dmg_file_list** file and only the **fully qualified pathname** of the **.dmg** files followed by a space and **encrypted: YES** in the **encrypted_dmg_file_list** file.

You can then manually delete the two files created by the command when finished with them.

Note: Once the command line is executed if may take a moment to process and output the contents of the **encrypted_dmg_file_list** file to the Terminal.  It will depend on just how many **.dmg** files there are.

Here is the full command line shown with line continuation so you make sure to copy and paste the entire line. (You can actually copy and paste the command line in this format too.)

```
mdfind '(kMDItemFSName=*.dmg)' | while IFS= read -r line; \
do printf "$line " & hdiutil isencrypted "$line"; \
done > dmg_file_list; grep ': YES' dmg_file_list > encrypted_dmg_file_list; \
clear; cat encrypted_dmg_file_list
```

Comment: I probably would grep for "encrypted: YES" in case the output of `hdiutil` changes in the future. Also if you use `>> dmg_file_list` you may want to remove an already existing file first (or use `> dmg_file_list`).

Comment: @patrix, The `>>` was typo.  I've corrected it.  As to greping for more then I did...  well things do change and code does get broken however it just needs to get fixed then. What I provided was a working example of just one way to accomplish the goal.  It's not the only way or necessarily the best way, just a way that worked on my system and can be adapted as necessary by whomever choses to use it.  As an example I could have written it so the encrypted_dmg_file_list file just had the fully qualified pathname as the file is designated as encrypted. I didn't because it's late and I'm tired. :)

Comment: this worked. thank you! but it exits with an error: `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /Users/user/encrypted_dmg_file_list.` any ideas?

Comment: Replace the `open` in the last line with `cat`, this will list the encrypted volumes directly in Terminal.

Comment: @melchior, per the `cat` suggestion by patrix, I've edited the command line as then it's not dependent on open any changes from the default with Launch Services.  You can always open the files manually in a text editor too.

Comment: @user3439894 On my system (Lion) your solution doesn't detect the encrypted test images I have created (trying to answer the question). `mdfind ... |xargs ... hdiutil | grep ...` shows them though. *Strange!*

Comment: @klanomath, I'm running OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion and did not test on any other version.

Answer (score 2):

Spotlight just doesn't have sufficient metadata to differentiate the filesystem choices stored inside a DMG. Put another way, it's like asking what Pages documents have French words in them just using `mdls`. The data to make that search isn't contained in metadata.

The proper command to check if a specific image file is encrypted is `hdiutil isencrypted /path/to/dmg`

Example:

```
host:~ user$ hdiutil isencrypted /Users/user/Downloads/test.dmg
```

Output:

```
encrypted: YES
blocksize: 512
uuid: DE78A7BE-2B64-4556-8EC9-93DFAC15A839
private-key-count: 0
passphrase-count: 1
max-key-count: 1
version: 2
```

Comment: How would this work together with mdfind etc?

Comment: @patrix I'm just trying to create the proper mdfind | xargs | hdiutil (| grep) command

Comment: This is +1 by me. It's bordering on "homework" and "do my work for me" which is what the OP seems to be seeking from recent questions, @patrix

Comment: @bmike it is close, but i can't figure out how to show the file that results in encrypted: YES. And for the record, it is very much a personal project, looking for a particular dmg out of hundreds from over ten years ago. this will help me a lot. long past the days of homework.

Comment: Excellent @melchior - learning pipe-fu is hard. My main suggestion is to pipe the output of the partial command to a file then cat that file to the next command.  Then you can see what your working with and if you have an odd error, try inspecting the data to see which piece is causing the failure

Comment: @bmike, i am certainly not above working with a list of files gathered from a cat output. in fact it is my usual goto workaround. in this case, i cannot figure out how to find out the name of the files that are encrypted. any tips?

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `mdfind -0` and `xargs` :

```
mdfind -0 "kMDItemFSName == '*.dmg'" | xargs -0 -IX ksh -c '
    if    hdiutil isencrypted "X"  2>&1 | grep -q "encrypted: YES"
    then  echo "X -ENCRYPTED"
    fi'
```